# MysQL Update if a count condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql-update, substring

I have a table which consists of 5000 rows. I need SQL command that could update each row by removing all values in "(...)" if only one couple of () is found.

Basically, if I have a name in a row:
*Name surname (extra info)*
I need to remove "*(extra info)*" and leave only Name surname
But if there is no additional couple of ()

If there is a row
*Name Surname(data) (extra info)*

The script should not amend this name

In simple words, I need to update a name where is only one ( or ) symbol

Many thanks

Comment: `WHERE name NOT LIKE '%(%)%(%)%` will skip rows that have multiple `(...)`

Answer (score 0):

can you try to find first '(' and substring to it ?

don't forget to use case for none ( in string

```
update userlogin
set fullname = case position('(' in FullName) 
when 0
then fullname
else substring(Fullname,1,position('(' in FullName) - 1) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of my question. I used select to let me check the result before applying it to update request. The script shows a table of 
3 columns: Id, Name, UpdatedName, where Name is what we have and UpdatedName what we will obtain

```
  SELECT `Id`,`Name`, 
    (case when ((LENGTH(`Name`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`Name`, '(', ''))) = 1) 
     THEN
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Name`, '(', 1)
     ELSE
          '-'
     END)
     as updated_name,
    FROM table
    WHERE (LENGTH(`Name`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`Name`, '(', ''))) = 1
    LIMIT 0,1500
```

P.S. I used Id to allow me to amend values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN fname = 'correct' THEN 'your condition'
    WHEN sname = 'correct' THEN 'your second condition'
    ELSE 'baz'
END AS fullname
FROM `databasetable`
```

or you can do as like also

```
CASE
    WHEN action = 'update' THEN
        UPDATE sometable SET column = value WHERE condition;
    WHEN action = 'create' THEN
        INSERT INTO sometable (column) VALUES (value);
END CASE
```